# Is there a way to use a function's argument to locate an item within an object using dot notation?

Tags: javascript

An example would be:

```
var test = {
apples: [],
oranges: [],
add: function (arrayInput) {
console.log(test.arrayInput.length)
}
```

Where arrayInput would console log either apples or oranges depending on what the user passed inside the add function. Is this possible in some way or does dot notation not accept variables?

Comment: You cannot guarantee the order of properties in an object in JavaScript, so you can't reference either array by index.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Could you give an example of how you would call this? Something more realistic that just `console.log` the `length`? (because if that's all you want then `add: function (a) { console.log(a.length); }` would do it)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
    var test = {
    apples: [],
    oranges: [],
    add: function (arrayInput) {
    console.log(this[arrayInput].length);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method should have access to it's passed in params without the this keyword. You only need "this" if you are referring to a property on your object. The answer should just be

```
var test = {
apples: [],
oranges: [],
add: function (arrayInput) {
console.log(arrayInput.length)
}
```

But you would use "this" if you wanted apples's length

```
var test = {
apples: [],
oranges: [],
add: function (arrayInput) {
console.log(this.apples.length)
}
```

If you expecting arrayInput to be the string "apples" or "oranges" and you want the properties on that you would use bracket notation.

```
var test = {
    apples: [],
    oranges: [],
    add: function (arrayInput) {
    console.log(this[arrayInput].length)
    }
```

In this case you are using "this" to access your object and the brackets let you access the property passed in by the string.

Answer (score 1):

Conan is correct, but the example is not very clear.

First, you can't use "dot notation" as you're asking; you have to use the property name - so `this.arrayInput.length` won't work but `this[arrayInput].length` *will*, assuming "arrayInput" is a string that refers to a property that is actually part of the object.

If you have your object `test` with its elements `apples` and `oranges` you can access those elements as `this[param]`. Let's see a better example - since there is  a method `add` let's use it to add things to the array elements in the object

```
var test = {
    apples: [],
    oranges: [],
    add: function (element, item) {
        this[element].push(item);
    },
    list: function (element) {
        console.log(this[element]);
    }
};
```

so now you can do `test.add('apples', 'red delicious')` and `test.add('granny smith')` then `test.list('apples')` as in this snippet:

```js
var test = {
    apples: [],
    oranges: [],
    add: function (element, item) {
        this[element].push(item);
    },
    list: function (element) {
        console.log(this[element]);
    }
};

test.add('apples', 'red delicious');
test.add('apples', 'granny smith');
test.add('oranges', 'navel');
test.list('apples');
test.list('oranges');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [] because u can access object key with [] also.

`console.log(this[arrayInput].length);`